# Need a Common Values according to list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a help in a complex query which is a result of a common values in a specific column according to a values in other column.
as mentioned in the table below:

```
StoreId  MaterialId MaterialCode    Date            SlotCode
1        1          CM              13/05/2021      **10-13**
1        1          CM              13/05/2021      16-19
1        3          MT              13/05/2021      04-07
1        3          MT              13/05/2021      07-10
1        3          MT              13/05/2021      **10-13**
1        3          MT              13/05/2021      13-16
1        3          MT              13/05/2021      16-19
```

The input is MaterialCode (I have 2 codes: CM & MT) and the result is the common value the column SlotCode which must be 13-13

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not also `16-19`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  SlotCode
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  MaterialCode IN ('CM', 'MT')
GROUP BY
  SlotCode
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT MaterialCode) = 2
```

Comment: @SmailBel, if this solves your problem, then you should formally "accept" the answer in order to remove it from the big pile of "questions without accepted answer".